# Colour swatch switching back to default randomly [Mage2]

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, color-swatches

For the past 2 days I've been monitoring my **configurable products** to see if there is an issue and not to my surprise, I see there is.

Basically, I set up a test product with a **colour**, and checked back `in hourly to see if it gets switched back to the default value.`

There are no other users on my site that can login and my password is pretty much... uncrackable.

Has anyone else had this issue? I know Magento 2 has quite a few bugs, but I can't find something alike this on the internet or on MageStack anywhere.

If anyone could help, that would be amazing!

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your case ?

Comment: I've edited product colour variants and they change back to default colour at random. We've monitored this and it seems there's an issue, I don't know what though. I'm just wondering if this is a common bug in Mage2?

Comment: Please share the screen shot

Comment: A screenshot of what, I'm sure you'd know what the colour would be before and after by reading this.. 'Blue' before, and 'Default' after.

Comment: Have you checked the URL ?